# Simplify redundant jquery's code

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code that works perfectly.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".a").mouseover(function(){
             $("body").addClass("a");    
           });
     $(".a").mouseout(function(){
            $("body").removeClass("a");
        });
     $(".b").mouseover(function(){
             $("body").addClass("b");    
        });

        $(".b").mouseout(function(){
            $("body").removeClass("b");
        });
    $(".c").mouseover(function(){
             $("body").addClass("c");    
            });
    $(".c").mouseout(function(){
            $("body").removeClass("c");
        });
                   ..........etc
                   });
<html>
    <img class="a" src="images/p1.jpg" >
    <img class="c" src="images/p3.png">
    <img class="d" src="images/p4.jpg">
</html>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to simplify it because it looks very redundant.

Thank you

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking... but you could bind those handlers in a loop. something like `['a', 'b'].forEach(x => $('.' + x).mouseover(() => $('body').addClass(x)))`

Comment: Opinion-based question, flagging for closing.

Comment: This type of question may be better received on [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside DOMready you could have a `hover` handler that toggles your class like this:

```
function onHover() {
    $('body').toggleClass(this.className);
}

$('img[class]').hover(onHover);
```

Note: Hover with a single function triggers on mouse in and out.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/65xq43g9/).

```js
function onHover() {
 $('body').toggleClass(this.className);
}

$('img[class]').hover(onHover);
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 10px;
}

.a {
    background-color: green;
}

.b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="a" src="https://placehold.it/300/300" />
<img class="b" src="https://placehold.it/300/300"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <body>
   <img class="a img" data-class="a" src="images/a.jpg">
   <img class="b img img-big" data-class="b" src="images/b.jpg">

   <a href="#nogo" class="a btn btn-external" data-class="a">A link</a>
   <a href="#nogo" class="b btn btn-external" data-class="b">B link</a>
 </body>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-class]').hover(function(){
    $('body').addClass($(this).data('class'));
  },function(){
    $('body').removeClass($(this).data('class'));
  });
});

 .a { background: red; }
 .b { background-color: blue; }
```

I used a data-class attribute so only the desired class is applied on the body. Just in case there is more than one class applied to the hovered element.

The data-class attribute can be applied on any html tag.

Answer (score 0):

this.className

What about something like that:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("img").mouseover(function(){
             $("body").addClass(this.className);    
           })
            .mouseout(function(){
               $("body").removeClass(this.className);
            });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a small simplification out of jQuery [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) and some loops.

```
function bindListeners() {
  var selectors = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  selectors.forEach(function (selector) {
    $('.' + selector).hover(function () {
      $('body').addClass(selector);
    }, function () {
      $('body').removeClass(selector);
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(bindListeners);
```